# Installation Registry Key Deleted, Unable to Uninstall

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-registry, uninstall, revo-uninstaller

When I try to re-install PowerBI, it won't let me because I cannot uninstall the previous version... what can I do to delete all existing traces of it so that I can uninstall?

I am on version 2.36.4434.381 and cannot find any free way to download this version (so that I can uninstall).

I have tried Revo Uninstaller and it didn't go all the way through so I deleted the registry key for it and now I can't even see it in the list of uninstall...

Now, I think I am stuck... unless I find this specific version...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running CCLeaner? The registry clean up tool in it could possibly remove all records of that software since it is no longer installed.

Answer (score 0):

After I forcibly remove the program from the registry, no program was able to see it.

After using the [Microsoft Fix-It tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17588/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed) fixed the issue and selecting the option where I had to select that the program does not show, I was able to select the program from a list and a few minutes later... it magically fully uninstalled.

I was then able to just install new version.